# Не прокручиваеться блок на смартфоне

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Сделал мини-чат для своего сайта, есть функцыя которая прокручивает блок в сам низ когда сообщение приходит и сам сколл уже внизу, на ноутбуке все нормально, на смартфоне не реагирует.. сообщение приходит, все обновляеться но не прокручиваеться блок, вот код:

```
function funcReadSuccess(data){
        $('.chat').html(data);
    }
    function funcReadChat(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "chatRead.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            success:funcReadSuccess
        });
        if($('.chat').scrollTop()+$('.chat').height()>=$('.chat')[0].scrollHeight){
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('.chat').scrollTop($('.chat').prop('scrollHeight'));}, 300);
    }
    }

<div style="max-height: 200pt; overflow-y: scroll; padding: 10pt; padding-top: 0pt; padding-bottom: 0pt;" class="chat">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему нашел!! я установил setTimeout для того чтоб успевали подгрузиться сообщения до того как програма прокрутит блок в конец списка сообщений. Проблема в том что я проверял на смартфонах с медленным 3G и 300 милисикунд указанных в програме просто не достаточно чтоб прогрузить много мообщений на медленном интернете, по сути скрипт исполнялся еще до того как сообщения обновлялись) а на компе там скорость приличная и все работало как надо. теперь все нормально и на смартфонах, просто поставил значение 1000.